# Why closed - Corchevel vs Klosters or St Moritz or Val Thoren?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

I'm trying to understand the socioeconomic allusions in the quote at [Corchevel vs Klosters or St Moritz or Val Thoren](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137506/95173).

Answer (score 5):

Asking for a ranking by prestige is inherently off-topic. *Prestige* (or *reputation*, *renown*, *cachet*, *clout*, etc.) cannot really be quantified; any ranking would be based primarily on personal priorities and opinions.

Second, asking to unravel all the social distinctions among four different ski resorts is too broad, and would most likely also come down to matters of personal opinion as to why one or the other should be seen in a certain light. Another person could draw different distinctions, and so it would be difficult to identify a single definitive answer, as befits the Stack Exchange model.

If you want to understand the socioeconomic differences among them, I'd say you are asking a question about socialization, not about travel, and I would deem it off-topic as it is not about travel as defined in the [help].

I don't agree with closing the question as a request for a trip plan, at least in its current state, but I do agree with closing it.